# Populate the `asp:Panel` in ASP.Net C# form with value rows selected of MySQL database table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, panel

I need to populate the `asp:Panel` in aspnet C# form with value rows selected of MySQL database table. in this example, I have two rows returned form table:

```
mysql> SELECT
    dt,
    hh,
    dtes,
    dori,
    sali
FROM
    `tbl_1` jjj
JOIN `tbl_2` kkk ON jjj.dori = kkk.dori
WHERE
    dtes IN ('X250')
AND dt IN (
    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
AND sali = 'S'
GROUP BY
    dt,
    hh,
    dori;
+------------+----------+------+-------------+------+
| dt         | hh       | dtes | dori        | sali |
+------------+----------+------+-------------+------+
| 2020-08-14 | 14:15:22 | X250 | X2001383334 | S    |
| 2020-08-14 | 14:42:48 | X250 | Y2001380456 | S    |
+------------+----------+------+-------------+------+
2 rows in set
```

This is my code behind to populate the `asp:Panel`:

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    int count = 0;

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count++;

            if (count >= 1)
            {
                //populate asp Panel;
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dt"]);

                txdtes.Text = reader["dtes"].ToString();
                txdt.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
                txhh.Text = reader["hh"].ToString();
                txdori.Text = reader["dori"].ToString();
                txsali.Text = reader["sali"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `asp:Panel` is populate only values from first row of query, but inserting the `while` loop it should not populate the `asp:Panel` with all the rows from the table?

How to do resolve this?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestion

Comment: Why are you incrementing the count at the beginning of the loop?  Count initially equals 0 and increments to 1 the first time in the loop.  The 2nd time in loop it is two and you do not go into the IF.

Comment: A Panel doesn't show multiple rows. Consider using a GridView and binding a DataTable to it.

Comment: You should also show your Page markup in the question.